# How to make my ionic4 project to load in full-screen mode in the mobile browser?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, fullscreen

I am using ionic 4 with angular for my newly created project. If my project loads in the mobile browser I want to hide the top and bottom bar or navigation of the browser which will make my website more native-mobile app like feels. But I don’t know how to do that. I am new to Ionic. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make your app fullscreen, on your `config.xml` file add: `<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />`

Comment: I don't find any `config.xml`  file in my project.

Comment: AS soon as you open the project folder you should see your config.xml file.

Comment: Config.xml not there previously after using this command I found the `config.xml` file `ionic integrations enable cordova`.

Comment: your solution is not working. I want the solution for the ionic website project not for  ionic mobile app project. The project will be viewed in a mobile browser not use as a mobile app.

Comment: What you have said even I also know that. You are not getting what I am saying. I want to give fullscreen experience only for `mobile browser` users.